# Difference between a strange chaotic and a strange non-chaotic attractor

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, hamiltonian, chaos-theory, fractals

Both of them look the same, but the SNA doesn't have positive lyapunov coefficients. What is the difference between them in terms of their attributes. A non-mathematical answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intuitive answer can be found in the definition of the Lyapunov coefficient, which essentially describes what happens over time to orbits of nearby starting points on the attractor. A chaotic strange attractor has a positive Lyapunov coefficient, which means that any two non-identical starting points on the attractor, no matter how close they are, will grow further and further apart over time in an exponential manner. Thus, any amount of uncertainty at all in an object's coordinates will lead to complete uselessness of any prediction in a short time. The behavior of strange chaotic attractors is "not periodic and not predictable."

A nonchaotic strange attractor will have non-positive (i.e. either zero or negative) Lyapunov coefficient. Starting points that are sufficiently close together will get exponentially closer and closer together over time (or in the case of Lyapunov exponent zero, will stay the same distance apart). Thus, even if there is some uncertainty in your initial conditions, prediction of a trajectory is still possible. The behavior of strange nonchaotic attractors is "not periodic, but still predictable."

Please note that the definition of "strange nonchaotic attractor" is still very much in flux and not quite rigorous; as such, there is some controversy over the attributes common to all SNAs. It's still very much a new field, so stay tuned.